# Create http websocket server on React Native app

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io

I would like exchange small data and text on React Native app in offline context. I know React is only for the View, but is it possible to create small http websocket serveur on React-Native app using `socket.io` ?

Answer (score 1):

socket io is a nodejs module and can't use in RN. you should use react-native-tcp

visit [TCP server mode with react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627883/tcp-server-mode-with-react-native)

and

https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use socket io client with react native app by simply installing this plugin [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)

Comment: He is asking for a websocket server.