# TCP server mode with react native

Tags: react-native

I want to program an APP to communicate over TCP socket but in my situation, I need server side, Is it possible in react native?

I tried to import socket.io but I got the below error:
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module 'http' from `C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Android\ReactNative\VestaSignageHandler\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js`: Module 'http' does not exist in the Haste module map

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
var io = require('socket.io')();

const port = 3000;
io.listen(port);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> App </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `react-native-tcp`